# Derivative Symbols

Tags: derivatives

My Calc teacher told us that $dy\over dx$ does not mean $dy$ divided by $dx$.  However, it seems like writing differential form involves only multiplying both sides by $dx$.  Why is this not just division?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a remnant of the origins of Calculus.  Essentially, $dx$ means a very tiny change in the $x$-value, while $dy$ is the small change between the old $y$ value and the new.  $dx \over dy$ is the ratio of the changes.  In many ways, this is division.  However, division by zero is invalid, and $dx$ and $dy$ should go to $0$ for a continuous function.